# Does moving a vector invalidate iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++11

If I have an iterator into vector `a`, then I move-construct or move-assign vector `b` from `a`, does that iterator still point to the same element (now in vector `b`)? Here's what I mean in code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator a_iter;
    std::vector<int> b;
    {
        std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        a_iter = a.begin() + 2;
        b = std::move(a);
    }
    std::cout << *a_iter << std::endl; // Is a_iter valid here?
    return 0;
}
```

Is `a_iter` still valid since `a` has been moved into `b`, or is the iterator invalidated by the move? For reference, `std::vector::swap` [does not invalidate iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4125186/185171).

Comment: Well the whole point of moving it is that you **don't** use it after. I can't say for sure whether it is or not, though.

Comment: @chris I am hoping that `a_iter` now references an element in `b` after `a` is moved.

Comment: Pedantic -- you didn't move-construct, you move-assigned.

Comment: My initial knee-jerk reaction to this question is the iterator is not valid or is in an undefined state, but I cannot find a reference in the Standard.

Comment: @JohnDibling edited :). My example originally was using move construction, but then I added the inner scope so `a` would go out of scope and switched to assignment at the same time.

Comment: Why don't you write a little program to test that? It shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: @Thomash:  I don't think hacking together a sample will be sufficient in this case.

Comment: @Thomash: If the answer is that it *does* invalidate iterators, then it's undefined behavior to dereference them, so how would you test it?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why iterators would be invalidated, but I can't find any quotes in the standard to support that... Since the validity of iterators after a swap is well-defined, it seems reasonable to think that the same reasoning can apply when moving (even more if we think about how `vectors` are implemented).

Comment: @Luc:  Iterators could be invalidated if the iterator class itself maintained pointers back in to the vector class.  Just spitballing.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Of course, I should have said "I can't think of a reasonable reason why the committee would have allowed iterators to be invalidated" :). And good luck for correctly implementing `swap` with iterators keeping a reference to their containers :)!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

While it might be reasonable to assume that `iterator`s are still valid after a `move`, I don't think the Standard actually guarantees this.  Therefore, the iterators are in an undefined state after the `move`.

---

There is no reference I can find in the Standard which *specifically states* that iterators that existed before a `move` are still valid *after* the `move`.

On the surface, it would seem to be perfectly reasonable to assume that an `iterator` is *typically* implemented as pointers in to the controlled sequence.  If that's the case, then the iterators would still be valid after the `move`.

But the implementation of an `iterator` is implementation-defined.  Meaning, so long as the `iterator` on a particular platform meets the requirements set forth by the Standard, it can be implemented in any way whatsoever.  It could, in theory, be implemented as a combination of a pointer back to the `vector` class along with an index.  If *that's* the case, then the iterators would become invalid after the `move`.

Whether or not an `iterator` is actually implemented this way is irrelevant.  It could be implemented this way, so without a specific guarantee from the Standard that post-`move` iterators are still valid, you cannot assume that they are.  Bear in mind also that there **is** such a guarantee for iterators after a `swap`.  This was specifically clarified from the previous Standard.  Perhaps it was simply an oversight of the Std comittee to not make a similar clarification for iterators after a `move`, but in any case there is no such guarantee.

Therefore, the long and the short of it is you can't assume your iterators are still good after a `move`.

### EDIT:

23.2.1/11 in Draft n3242 states that:

> Unless otherwise specified (either explicitly or by defining a
>   function in terms of other functions), invoking a container member
>   function or passing a container as an argument to a library function
>   shall not invalidate iterators to, or change the values of, objects
>   within that container.

This might lead one to conclude that the iterators are valid after a `move`, but I disagree.  In your example code, `a_iter` was an iterator in to the `vector` `a`.  After the `move`, that container, `a` has certainly been changed.  My conclusion is the above clause does not apply in this case.

Comment: +1 But, maybe you can reasonably assume they _are_ still good after a move - but just know that it may not work if you switch compilers. It works in every compiler I just tested, and it probably always will.

Comment: @Dave:  Reliance on Undefined Behavior is a very slippery slope and, pedantically, technically invalid.  You're best off just not doing it.

Comment: I would normally agree, but it would be hard to write a swap that maintains valid iterators and a move assignment which does not. It would almost take intentional effort by the library writer to have the iterators invalidated. Besides, undefined is my favorite kind of behavior.

Comment: @Sven Marnach:  I never know Weather to use Weather or Whether :)

Comment: This is [LWG 2321](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-active.html#2321)

Comment: Regarding "_After the `move`, that container, `a` has certainly been changed. My conclusion is the above clause does not apply in this case._" - Couldn't the same argument be made for `swap`? It changes both containers. Yet, if we do `std::swap(a, b);`, valid iterators to elements in `a` are now guaranteed to be valid iterators to elements in `b` and vice versa.

Answer (score 12):

I think the edit that changed move construction to move assignment changes the answer.

At least if I'm reading table 96 correctly, the complexity for move construction is given as "note B", which is constant complexity for anything except `std::array`. The complexity for move *assignment*, however, is given as linear.

As such, the move construction has essentially no choice but to copy the pointer from the source, in which case it's hard to see how the iterators could become invalid.

For move assignment, however, the linear complexity means it *could* choose to move individual elements from the source to the destination, in which case the iterators will almost certainly become invalid.

The possibility of move assignment of elements is reinforced by the description: "All existing elements of a are either move assigned to or destroyed". The "destroyed" part would correspond to destroying the existing contents, and "stealing" the pointer from the source -- but the "move assigned to" would indicate moving individual elements from source to destination instead.

Comment: I see the same thing as you in table 96, but I'm shocked move construction and move assignment have different complexity requirements! Does a conforming implementation _have_ to match the complexity in that table, or can it do better? (AKA: is a std::vector that copies the pointer to it's data in the move assignment op standard conformant?)

Comment: @Dave:  A comforming implementation must do no worse than any performance guarantees dictated in the Standard.

Comment: I actually think it is linear in terms of the size of the container being assigned to. This is the same as the destructor being linear, it has to destroy all existing items, a problem the move-constructor does not have as there are no existing items.

Comment: Why wouldn't they require constant complexity for std::vector move assignment?! (and all other containers...)

Comment: @Dave: Consider assigning a container of 2 elements to one that had 50. One way or another, the extra 48 elements have to be destroyed. It can either destroy *all* the elements in the destination, then move the pointer to the source buffer into the destination container, or else it can move the 2 elements to the destination, and destroy the other 48. Either way it needs to be linear though.

Comment: It's not just linear in the number of elements to be destroyed. As stated in [container.requirements.general]/7 move construction always moves the allocator, move assignment only moves the allocator if `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is true, if it's not true and the allocators are not equal then the existing storage cannot be moved and so there's a possible reallocation and each element is moved individually.

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr : Yes, moving a `std::vector<T, A>` possibly invalidates the iterators**

<sub>The common case (with `std::allocator` in place) is that invalidation does not happen but there is no guarantee and switching compilers or even the next compiler update might make your code behave incorrect if you rely on the fact the your implementation currently does not invalidate the iterators.</sub>

---

*On move assignment*:

The question whether `std::vector` iterators can actually remain valid after move-assignment is connected with the allocator awareness of the vector template and depends on the allocator type (and possibly the respective instances thereof).

In every implementation I have seen, move-assignment of a `std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>`**<sup>1</sup>** will not actually invalidate iterators or pointers. There is a problem however, when it comes down to making use of this, as **the standard just cannot guarantee that iterators remain valid for any move-assignment of a `std::vector` instance in general, because the container is allocator aware.**

Custom allocators may have state and if they do not propagate on move assignment and do not compare equal, the vector must allocate storage for the moved elements using its own allocator.

Let:

```
std::vector<T, A> a{/*...*/};
std::vector<T, A> b;
b = std::move(a);
```

Now if

1. `std::allocator_traits<A>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value == false &&`
2. `std::allocator_traits<A>::is_always_equal::value == false &&` (*possibly as of c++17*)
3. `a.get_allocator() != b.get_allocator()`

then `b` will allocate new storage and move elements of `a` one by one into that storage, thus invalidating all iterators, pointers and references.

The reason is that fulfillment of above condition **1.** forbidds move assignment of the allocator on container move. Therefore, we have to deal with two different instances of the allocator. If those two allocator objects now neither always compare equal (**2.**) nor actually compare equal, then both allocators have a different state. An allocator `x` may not be able to deallocate memory of another allocator `y` having a different state and therefore a container with allocator `x` cannot just steal memory from a container which allocated its memory via `y`.

If the allocator propagates on move assignment or if both allocators compare equal, then an implementation will very likely choose to just make `b` own `a`s data because it can be sure to be able to deallocate the storage properly.

**<sup>1</sup>**: `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment` and `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>::is_always_equal` both are typdefs for `std::true_type` (for any non-specialized `std::allocator`).

---

*On move construction*:

```
std::vector<T, A> a{/*...*/};
std::vector<T, A> b(std::move(a));
```

The move constructor of an allocator aware container will move-construct its allocator instance from the allocator instance of the container which the current expression is moving from. Thus, the proper deallocation capability is ensured and the memory can (and in fact will) be stolen because move construction is (except for `std::array`) bound to have constant complexity.

*Note: There is still no guarantee for iterators to remain valid even for move construction.*

---

*On swap*:

Demanding the iterators of two vectors to remain valid after a swap (now just pointing into the respective swapped container) is easy because swapping only has defined behaviour if

1. `std::allocator_traits<A>::propagate_on_container_swap::value == true ||`
2. `a.get_allocator() == b.get_allocator()`

Thus, if the allocators do not propagate on swap and if they do not compare equal, swapping the containers is undefined behaviour in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Since there's nothing to keep an iterator from keeping a reference or pointer to the original container, I'd say you can't rely on the iterators remaining valid unless you find an explicit guarantee in the standard.

Comment: +1:  I would agree with this assesment, and for what it's worth I've been looking for such a reference for the last 30 minutes and I can't find anything. :)

Comment: Agreed with John Dibling, the closest reference is that iterators are not invalidated if two containers are swapped, which seems to indicate that it should be valid, but I did not find any such guarantee. It is surprising how silent the standard regarding move of containers.

Comment: Is it not the other way around? Can't you assume that iterators remain valid unless otherwise specified by the standard? This is what I understand from this quote: `Unless otherwise speciﬁed (either explicitly or by deﬁning a function in terms of other functions), invoking a container member function or passing a container as an argument to a library function shall not invalidate
iterators to, or change the values of, objects within that container.` [container.requirements.general]

Comment: @Luc:  You should post that as an answer before I steal it for myself. :)

Comment: @JohnDibling: Please, feel free to update your answer with this :).

Comment: @Luc: But moving from a container certainly *does* change the values of the container, from having them to not having them.  So, I would presume that iterators can also be invalidated.

Comment: Wouldn't `vector::swap` being constant time and also not invalidating iterators prevent `vector::iterator` from containing a pointer to the original container?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: This is changing the container itself, not the objects contained. However, as noted by Jerry, in the case of move assignment, the objects contained by the source container can be move assigned from, meaning that their value can be changed (whether or not this is clearly specified in the standard is debatable). Anyway, the fact that the values of contained objects can be changed does not imply that iterators will be invalidated, does it?

Comment: @LucTouraille: I don't know.  I'm only allowed to comprehend so much standardese per month, and I've exceeded my limit.

Comment: @Benjamin : But it's not even halfway through! ;-]