# Does std::move guarantee vector.data() does not change?

Tags: c++, move, stdvector, move-semantics

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdint>
#include <bit>

template <typename T>
std::pair<std::vector<uint8_t>, T*> create_data_vec() 
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> data(sizeof(T));
    auto ptr = std::bit_cast<T*>(data.data());
    return {std::move(data), ptr};
}
```

In C++20, is `ptr` guaranteed to point to the same data after returning?
I tested this on gcc 11.3, and it holds, but does the *standard* guarantee it?

Example:
https://godbolt.org/z/bG3rda3Ws

Note that this is not the final code. There is some placement new stuff as well, so this is just a minimum working example.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76739542/is-stdvector-guaranteed-to-steal-resource-on-move-construction

Comment: [OT] Should it be `auto ptr = new (data.data()) T{};`?

Comment: @Jarod42, As noted, yes. In the original code I do that, but it is not relevant for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector#Notes

> After container move construction (overload (8)), references, pointers, and iterators (other than the end iterator) to other remain valid, but refer to elements that are now in `*this`. The current standard makes this guarantee via the blanket statement in [[container.reqmts]/67](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.reqmts#67), and a more direct guarantee is under consideration via [LWG issue 2321](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2321).

So yes it is guaranteed.

Comment: "remain valid, but refer to elements that are now in `*this`" says nothing about `ptr()`. It'll be valid for the moved-to (and moved-from) `*this`, but I don't see any guarantee, whatsoever, that it's unchanged.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: NOt sure to understand what you mean. "`data.data()`" refers now to the returned `vector.data()`.

Comment: @Jarod42, Thanks. This was exactly what I was looking for. Will read the CTOR doc before posting next time ´:)