Designing function API to avoid object lifetime problems
I've got a function that returns a lambda.
auto make_scanner(std::vector<int> const &v) {
    auto begin = v.cbegin();
    auto end = v.cend();
    return [begin, end] () mutable -> int {
        return (begin != end) ? *begin++ : 0;
    };
}

Note that the lambda captures iterators into the vector, but not the vector itself.  In the common use case, this is fine:
// Common Use Case
std::vector<int> data = {1, 2, 3};
auto scanner = make_scanner(data);
for (int x = scanner(); x != 0; x = scanner()) {
    // compute something
}

But if the caller makes a scanner from an unnamed temporary vector, the lambda is left with dangling iterators:
// Incorrect Use Case
auto scanner = make_scanner(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3});
// Invoking scanner() is UB because the iterators reference
// the vector after its lifetime.

In a non-optimized build (i.e., a debug build), this will usually work as intended even though the code is wrong.  In an optimized build, if you're lucky, it will crash or at least cause tests to fail.
Is there a way to fail compilation when make_scanner is called with an unnamed temporary vector while still allowing the common use case?
I've been trying out various overloads with r-value references, but the answer eludes me.
(Yes, I realize it's possible to use a non-temporary vector and still end up with dangling iterators in the lambda.  I'm not concerned with those case at this time.)

Not sure if you use the Abseil library in your codebase, but if so there is an annotation to catch this exact problem auto make_scanner(std::vector<int> const &v ABSL_ATTRIBUTE_LIFETIME_BOUND)

In general I would be really worried about invalidated iterators.  And UB is UB debug build or not (don't ever go near it)

It is also not clear WHAT problem scan should solve for you, and I suspect there are better ways to model that.

Short answer: No. This is the one yet unsolved problem of C++.

@red.wave THE ?

This is fairly easy to achieve leveraging deleted functions.  The first thing we need to know is that when overloading a function the parameter T&& takes precedence over an overload with the parameter const T& when the function is called with an rvalue.
If you then delete the rvalue reference overload then overload resolution will chose that function for rvalues and you will get a compiler error for using a deleted function.
For your code that becomes
auto make_scanner(std::vector<int> const &v) {
    auto begin = v.cbegin();
    auto end = v.cend();
    return [begin, end] () mutable -> int {
        return (begin != end) ? *begin++ : 0;
    };
}

auto make_scanner(std::vector<int> &&v) = delete;

and you can see it working in this live example.

Alternatively, capture ownership of the vector to the lambda itself to avoid lifetime problems: auto make_scanner(std::vector<int>&& v) { return [begin=v.cbegin(), end=v.cend(), vv=std::move(v)] () mutable -> int { return (begin != end) ? *begin++ : 0; }; }

Or make ownership of the vector shared (shared_ptr) and capture the shared_ptr by value. make_scanner(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> vector) (this is a pattern I regularely use in multithreaded code), where multipe threads need to access the vector (but lifetime of the threads in not know in advance)

@Eljay -- you can't capture iterators, because they are not guaranteed to be valid after move

@Gene • aww pewp.  More info at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11022116/4641116

@Eljay -- AFAIK, the standard guarantees only swap preserving iterators, so you can use it instead, but even at that the end() iterator can be invalidated: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/container.requirements#container.reqmts-66.6

The "fix" would be to move the vector into a shared pointer, then the iterators ought to be valid for the life of the scanner lambda.

@Pepiijn Kramer and others:  In order to make the question concise, I showed a substantially simplified version of one of the actual function templates.  (I wouldn't do something so esoteric if it were just a vector of ints.)  Capturing the data is not always possible or practical.  I appreciate std::shared_ptr when sharing ownership across threads, but that feels like overkill here.  My lambda-maker has the same dangling reference problems as std::string_view and std::span, both of which I find useful despite the foot guns.

@AdrianMcCarthy But if you do see passing Rvalues as potential pitfalls, you could do as Gene suggests and just move them into the generator (scanner). The interface would feel nicer i.m.o.

@TedLyngmo:  I appreciate the suggestion.  I think my sample code is a bit too much of a simplification to convey what's really going on.  Nevertheless, this answer solved my problem.  Deleting the r-value reference overload solved the problem in a satisfactory way for me.

@AdrianMcCarthy Yeah, it was going to be my suggestion too. NathanOliver was a mere ~10 seconds quicker than I was to post (so I did not) and I upvoted his answer of course. deleteing could be the norm if you haven't investigated properly what moving would entail and then open up for moving in those cases you've deemed it safe. Oh, rambling.... I've got a bit of a fever here :-)


Is there a way to fail compilation when make_scanner is called with an
unnamed temporary vector while still allowing the common use case?

You can provide an rvalue deleted overload.
auto make_scanner(const std::vector<int>&& v) = delete;

You can also make a working overload for rvalue vector, it would have to move vector inside lambda:
auto make_scanner(std::vector<int>&& v) {
    return [v = std::move(v), idx = size_t(0)] () mutable -> int {
        return idx != v.size() ? v[idx++] : 0;
    };
}

Here is a demo.
