# Does the standard specify small-object optimization?

Tags: c++

I know that `std::string` has small-string optimization, and both `std::any` and `std::function` have small-object optimization.

Are these optimizations just implementation details, or are they  specified in standard? If they're specified in standard, then which classes have small-object optimization?

I found some related words in spec:

> [22.7.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/any.class.general#3)：Implementations should avoid the use of dynamically allocated memory for a small contained value. However, any such small-object optimization shall only be applied to types T for which is_­nothrow_­move_­constructible_­v is true.

But I can't find a specification for small-object optimization.

Any additional supplements and recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: "*Are these optimizations just implementation details*" - yes "*are they specified in standard*" - no

Comment: When it gets down to the nuts-and-bolts, the C++ Standard is pretty hands-off in order to offer plenty of leeway for optimization and strange implementations targeted at strange problems.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Does that mean `std::string` may not have small string optimization for some compiler?

Comment: @Mes yes, SSO is optional. It is an implementation detail, and while most modern implementations do utilize it, not every one does.

Comment: @RemyLebeau okay, that sovle my question, thank you very much. But I wonder if most container utilize small object optimization, just like `std::any` and `std::function` do, ofc in most compiler.

Comment: No, other containers do not. Most famously std::vector is not allowed because of the iterator invalidation rules, like iterators staying valid after a swap with another vector! https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap

Comment: @BoP okay, got it, that surprise me a lot, thank you very much :)

Comment: In standardese, "should" means that it's highly recommended. It does **not** impose a requirement (a requirement would use "shall"). So the quoted text does not require small-string optimization.

Comment: @Bop Just to be clear (in case anyone gets misled over this) cppreference is playing a bit fast and loose with their terminology here.  The iterators remain valid, but now refer to the _'other'_ vector, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4125186/5743288.  Apologies if this sounds obvious - it could hardly work any other way.